# Installing Moodle on Bluemix PHP runtime: missing extensions

Tags: php, moodle, ibm-cloud, php-extension

I am trying to install Moodle on the default PHP runtime on Bluemix. But I run into the following problem with missing extensions:

```
manifest.yml
buildpack: php_buildpack
```

I cloned the default PHP runtime to my localhost, included the Moodle distribution into the same directory and could run everything out of the box. But when uploading it to Bluemix I get errors, though the build and deploy stage succeeds:

```
ERR The extension 'simplexml' is not provided by this buildpack.
ERR The extension 'tokenizer' is not provided by this buildpack.
ERR The extension 'dom' is not provided by this buildpack.
ERR The extension 'json' is not provided by this buildpack.
ERR The extension 'pcre' is not provided by this buildpack.
ERR The extension 'reflection' is not provided by this buildpack.
ERR The extension 'spl' is not provided by this buildpack.
```

The CF docs say that I need to add a '.bp-config/options.json' file to include the missing extensions to the manifest's buildpack. So this is my options.json

```
{
  "PHP_EXTENSIONS": [
    "simplexml", 
    "tokenizer",
    "dom",
    "json",
    "pcre",
    "reflection",
    "spl"
  ]
}
```

After which I still get the following errors in the cf-push log:

```
ERR The extension 'simplexml' is not provided by this buildpack.
ERR The extension 'tokenizer' is not provided by this buildpack.
ERR The extension 'dom' is not provided by this buildpack.
ERR The extension 'json' is not provided by this buildpack.
ERR The extension 'pcre' is not provided by this buildpack.
ERR The extension 'reflection' is not provided by this buildpack. 
ERR The extension 'spl' is not provided by this buildpack.
```

If I add 'pcre' to the composer.json file and update lock, it still shows the same error, although now 'pcre' leads the error messages on top.

```
{
    "require":{
        "ext-pcre": "*"
    },
    "require-dev": 
    {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.8.*",
        "phpunit/dbUnit": "1.4.*",
        "moodlehq/behat-extension": "1.30.1",
        "ext-pcre": "*"
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: that should be 'lib-pcre' (not ext-pcre) but either way, it doesn't solve anything.

Comment: Maybe you should try installing a local version in your computer, create a docker image based on it and putting the docker image onto Bluemix. That would be a hassle free way I believe.